# Show that $\langle 3, y^4-x,y^{12}-x^3+y-1 \rangle$ is a maximal ideal in $\Bbb{Z}[X,Y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Ok, so Im trying to solve an excercise which says:

> Show that $m=\langle 3, y^4-x,y^{12}-x^3+y-1 \rangle$ is a maximal ideal in $\Bbb{Z}[X,Y]$

With sugestion: Study $\Bbb{Z}[X,Y]/m$ and recall that $\Bbb{Z}[X,Y]/m \cong (\Bbb{Z}[X,Y]/\langle 3\rangle)\big /(m / \langle 3 \rangle)$ ...

So I think the objective is to show that $\Bbb{Z}[X,Y]/m$ is a field. However I don't see how the second isomorphism theorem is helping in any way. Can somebody give me $\textit{just}$ a hint?

Comment: If you mod out by $3$ first, then $\mathbb Z[X, Y]/m \cong (\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z)[X, Y]/(Y^4 - X, Y^{12} - X^3 + Y - 1)$. If you further mod out by $Y^4 - X$, then you're really setting $X = Y^4$. Hence, the previous is $\cong (\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z)[Y]/(Y^{12} - Y^{12} + Y - 1)$